# Automated testing with makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm extremely new to makefiles and just spent a full day trying to figure out how to automate my testing. For this project I have one program, main.c and it accepts as parameters an input and an output file. The input file is of the form "test-{filler}.txt" so an example file could be "test-invalid-opcode.txt". The output file would be of the form "out-{filler}.txt", so it would be of the form "out-invalid-opcode.txt". I would then want to compare the output with the correct output saved in "correct-{filler}.txt", so this would be "correct-invalid-opcode.txt". Each test would therefore have an input, output, and correct output. I would want to check if the output and correct output have any differences and I would want this to run on every test file with the prefix "test-". I read through a lot of the makefile spec and a lot of different examples, but I'm really confused as to how to handle this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is what I have to run one test:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-o

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.o $<

.PHONY: test
test: main.o test-provided.txt test-out.cs
    ./program test-provided.txt test-out.txt
    diff -q test-out.txt out-provided.txt
```

The layout of what I want the automatic test to be is something like

```
.PHONY: autotest
autotest: program
    $(foreach <file with "test-" prefix> run:
        main.o <test-name> <out-name>
        diff -q <correct-name> <out-name>
```

But I really am lost on how to go about implementing that.

Thank you and sorry I couldn't post more code. I tried a lot of different things, but none of them were even close enough to be worth posting.

### Edit to show working final version:

```
program: main.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $a $<

TEST_INPUTS := $(wildcard test-*.txt)
.PHONY: autotest $(TEST_INPUTS)

autotest: $(TEST_INPUTS)

$(TEST_INPUTS): test-%.txt: program
    echo '' > out-$*.txt
    ./$< $@ out-$*.txt
    diff -q correct-$*.txt out-$*.txt
```

Comment: Do not use `make`'s `foreach` in recepies, use `bash`'s `for`. You can have a look how I do similar thing here https://github.com/igagis/svgren/blob/master/tests/samples/makefile#L33 Notice, there is `for` loop through all files to be tested, then there is a `check` program run on each file and then program exit status is checked.

Comment: How would I check if the prefix is “test-“ and then use whatever comes after “test-“ and create an output file with the same name and the prefix “out?”

Comment: You should absolutely _NOT_ name your program `main.o`.  A `.o` file is an object file and cannot be run as an executable.  Although you are building it as an executable, so it can be run, naming it with a `.o` extension will be really confusing to everyone reading your makefile.

Comment: Just changed it to `program`. Still getting the same issue

Comment: My comment above was not intended to solve anything.  it was a stylistic comment.  Note you need to change the name in the recipe as well.  Better is to use automatic variables like `$@` and`$<`

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the extra info

Comment: Note that your rule for `program` is still wrong here: it still uses `main.o` in the recipe.  You should change it to `$@` or at least `program`.

Comment: Updated again and still same issue

Comment: Again, my comments here are only related to style and aren't expected to fix any errors (although this last one was an error: it would never create the file `program` as it was).  See the answer below for discussion of the problems you're having.

Comment: Fantastic. It fixed the issue. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general using loops with make is not very "make-ish".  A makefile is an entire language fundamentally based on iteration and recursion so trying to do "extra" iteration inside a recipe is often redundant.

If you need to iterate over something, most *especially* when that something is files, you should attempt to work with make by taking advantage of its target/prerequisite organization.  Above you give an algorithm:

```
$(foreach <file with "test-" prefix> run:
    main.o <test-name> <out-name>
    diff -q <correct-name> <out-name>
```

which is perfectly suited to make's default behavior.  To translate this into a makefile you write a rule which invokes a single iteration of the loop, then use prerequisites to run it for the files you want.  Something like this:

```
TEST_INPUTS := $(wildcard test-*.txt)
.PHONY: autotest $(TEST_INPUTS)

autotest: $(TEST_INPUTS)

$(TEST_INPUTS): test-%.txt: program
        $< $@ test-out.txt
        diff -q test-out.txt out-$*.txt
```

Not only is this much more make-like but it has other advantages: for example you can run `make test-provided.txt` and it will run just that one test instead of all the tests.

You have to use [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) here not normal pattern rules because `.PHONY` targets can't work with pattern rules.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. When I attempt to run this, I get `make: Nothing to be done for `autotest'.` I edited my question to include the code I am attempting to run now.

Comment: That means that the wildcard function is returning the empty string.  Do you actually have files named things like `test-foo.txt` in your directory?  If you run `ls test-*.txt` at the shell prompt where you would run `make autotest` does it print anything?

Comment: Yep. It prints test-provided.txt
test-duplicate-label.txt test-unrecognized-label.txt
test-large-offset.txt  test-unrecognized-opcode.txt
test-out.txt

Comment: If you add `$(info TEST_INPUTS = $(TEST_INPUTS))` on the line after the assignment then run `make` what does it print for that value?

Comment: `TEST_INPUTS = test-duplicate-label.txt test-large-offset.txt test-out.txt test-provided.txt test-unrecognized-label.txt test-unrecognized-opcode.txt
make: `program' is up to date.`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have one remaining issue. I'm getting the error `make: program: No such file or directory`. I updated my code again in the question

Comment: You probably  need to run `./program` not just `program`.  You likely don't have your current directory in your `$PATH` (which is a Good Thing, it's a security hole to have `.` in `$PATH`).  So use `./$<` in your recipe.